# Blink GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a bit of a noob to programming and I am trying to make a GameObject , deactivate and reactivate over a set amount of seconds.For example I want my star to slowly blink before it goes away, to create a cool looking effect. If there is a better way of using this method done with out using SetActive(false) and what not , please feel free to give me your method - This is my code , Sorry if its messy i gotta get better at this but i will in due time

Thanks guys

```
//Timers
public float ScoreTimer;
public float[] TimeMarkStamp;

//Scoring
public int totalCollStars;
[Space]
public int maxStars = 5;

public GameObject[] StarImages;


// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    ScoreTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (ScoreTimer <= TimeMarkStamp[0])
    {
        Debug.Log("It works");
        StarImages[0].SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (ScoreTimer <= TimeMarkStamp[1])
    {
        Debug.Log("It workds" + TimeMarkStamp[1]);
        StarImages[1].SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (ScoreTimer <= TimeMarkStamp[2])
    {
        Debug.Log("It works" + TimeMarkStamp[2]);
        StarImages[2].SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (ScoreTimer <= TimeMarkStamp[3])
    {
        //This is not working 
        InvokeRepeating("flickerEffect", 3f, 1f);
    }
}

void flickerEffect()
{
    bool flickCheck = false;


    if (flickCheck == false)
    {
        StarImages[3].SetActive(true);
        flickCheck = true;
    }
    else if (flickCheck == true)
    {
        StarImages[3].SetActive(false);
        flickCheck = false;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try looking/googling into the `Coroutines`, but the programming itself must be pretty strong with you if you are to make games.

Comment: true, simplest method would be to make use coroutines, but depending on what to achieve you may want to use other methods of making objects invisible.

Comment: Okay awsome thanks heaps i will have a good look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is a better way of using this method done with out using
>   SetActive(false) and what not

Yes, there is a better way, other than using the `SetActive` function. You should change the alpha `color` of the GameObject from `0` to `1` back and forth. After that you can then disable the GameObject with `SetActive`. This saves how much garbage would have been generated when repeatedly calling the `SetActive` function.

If this is a 3D GameObject, change the **Rendering Mode** from Opaque(default) to *Fade* or *Transparent*.

A simple function that can do this:

```
void blink(GameObject obj, float blinkSpeed, float duration)
{
    StartCoroutine(_blinkCOR(obj, blinkSpeed, duration));
}

IEnumerator _blinkCOR(GameObject obj, float blinkSpeed, float duration)
{
    obj.SetActive(true);
    Color defualtColor = obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;

    float counter = 0;
    float innerCounter = 0;

    bool visible = false;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        innerCounter += Time.deltaTime;

        //Toggle and reset if innerCounter > blinkSpeed
        if (innerCounter > blinkSpeed)
        {
            visible = !visible;
            innerCounter = 0f;
        }

        if (visible)
        {
            //Show
            show(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            //Hide
            hide(obj);
        }

        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }

    //Done Blinking, Restore default color then Disable the GameObject
    obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = defualtColor;
    obj.SetActive(false);
}

void show(GameObject obj)
{
    Color currentColor = obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
    currentColor.a = 1;
    obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = currentColor;
}

void hide(GameObject obj)
{
    Color currentColor = obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;
    currentColor.a = 0;
    obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = currentColor;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
void Start()
{
    blink(gameObject, 0.2f, 5f);
}
```

If this is a `SpriteRender`, you have to replace all the `obj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color` code with `obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color`.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help it works perfectly for what i am trying to do !!! ^_^ awsome explanation and very clear